# ¿Como extraigo los valores de un objeto?

Tags: typescript, angular

Estoy intentado hacer un *login* simple utilizando información sacada de una base de datos en forma de `json`. 
Esa información la saqué utilizando `http.get` y la guarde en una variable llamada `this.info`.
Entonces lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Extraer los valores de un objecto dentro de un `json` (en este caso `this.info`) y guardarlos en una variable.
2. Utilizar esa variable y compararla con una variable "enlazada" con información de un `[(ngModel)]` y si es verdad que muestre un `alert`.

Ya he intentado utilizando `for`, `foreach`, `map`. Y al momento de hacer la comparación marca como falso.

He aquí el código que utilizado como mencione arriba.
**map**

```
us: any;
cn: any;`
this.us = this.info.map(({ username }) => username);
this.cn = this.info.map(({ contrasena }) => contrasena);
```

**for**

```
us = [];
cn = [];
for (let  x of this.info) {
  this.us.push(x.username);
  this.cn.push(x.password);
}
```

**forEach**

```
this.info.forEach(function(x) {
    this.us.push(x.usuario);
    this.cn.push(x.contrasena);
});
```

Pero sale erróneo al momento de realizar lo siguiente:

```
// this.usern y this.passw vienen del [(ngModel)]
if (this.usern == this.us) {
    if(this.passw == this.cn) {
        alert('Datos Correctos');
    } 
} else {
    alert('Datos Incorrectos');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema lo tienes en la comprobación, no en el map/for/forEach.

Si analizas la primera línea, estas comparando un string, this.usern, con un array, this.us. Imagino que lo que querrás hacer es que compruebe primero es que el usuario esté dentro del array. Eso lo puedes hacer con `indexOf`. `indexOf` devuelve la posición dentro del array donde se encuentra la primera ocurrencia. Si no lo encuentra, devuelve -1.

```
let pos = this.us.indexOf(this.usern);
if (pos > -1){
    // usuario existe
    if(this.passw == this.cn[pos]){
        alert("Correcto");
    }else{
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
    }
}else{
    alert("Usuario no existe");
}
```

Por otro lado, lo que estás haciendo no lo pongas en una app de verdad nunca, ya que no debes enviar las contraseñas de los usuarios al cliente, sería muy fácilmente hackeable. Las contraseñas se deben de quedar siempre en el servidor y hasheadas.